# How to perform Monte Carlo simulations to price a Forward contract under the Schwartz mean reverting model?

Tags: option-pricing, programming, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, mean-reversion

> Objective: (1) Implement the Euler Explicit Method for solving the PDE for option prices under the Schwartz mean reverting model. (2) Compare with a Monte Carlo simulation.

I'm stuck with point 1 (see this [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58075)) so in the meanwhile I'm working on point 2. Basically, I have 200 monthly spot prices of a commodity (oil) following the Schwartz mean reverting SDE $dS = \alpha(\mu-\log S)Sdt + \sigma S dW$. This commodity is the underlying asset of the Forward contract with price at delivery $F(S,T)$, where $S$ is the spot price at time 0 and $T$ is the expiry time. Such a contract is equivalent to having an option with $\text{payoff}(S_T)=S_T-K$, where $K=F(S,T)$ is the strike price.

Letting $\tau=T-t$ be the time to expiry, the formula for the price of the forward contract is

$$\tag{1}F(S,\tau)=\exp\Big(e^{-\alpha\tau}\log S +(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}-\frac{\mu-r}{\alpha})(1-e^{-\alpha\tau})+\frac{\sigma^2}{4\alpha}(1-e^{-2\alpha\tau})\Big)$$

and the value of the equivalent option is $V(S,t)=e^{-r(T-t)}F(S,t)$. ($\alpha, \sigma, \mu$ are estimated from data)

Knowing this information, how to run (I'm using matlab but other languages are fine too) a Monte Carlo simulation to price the option?

I read these are the steps

- generate a large number of random price paths for the underlying asset
- for each path compute the payoff of the option
- compute the average of all payoffs
- discount the average to today

but since I'm working with real data of oil spot prices, I'm a bit confused: how can we obtain the value of the option having an underlying commodity with known spot prices by generating random spot price paths?

Moreover how to perform the next steps using the above formulas?

---

### EDIT: First attempt

I wrote the code which computes what I think (can you confirm?) is the exact solution for option pricing (`V_exact`) and then computes the approximating solution by means of Monte Carlo simulation (`V_Monte_Carlo`). The MC simulation uses the first spot price (real data) and the estimated parameters to 'randomly' compute the next spot prices. To compute the spot prices, instead of using the equation for $dS$ that I wrote above it's easier to use this one which is obtained from $dS$ by letting $X=\log S$.

$$\tag{2}X_t = X_0 e^{-\alpha t} + \mu^*(1-e^{-\alpha t}) + \underbrace{\sigma e^{-\alpha t} \int_0^t e^{\alpha s} dW_s}_Z$$

where $\mu^* = \mu-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}$ and $Z \sim \sigma\sqrt{\dfrac{1-e^{-2\alpha t}}{2\alpha}} \cdot N(0,1)$

These are the steps for the Monte Carlo simulation:

1. The first price `F` of the forward contract - and so of the option `V` too - is set to 0 since there is no cost to enter a forward contract. Compute the first value of $X$ by taking the logarithm of the first spot price
2. compute the next value of $X$ using the formula (2)
3. compute the next value of the spot price by taking the exponential of $X$
4. compute the next price `F` of the forward contract using formula (1)
5. compute the next price `V` of the option using $V(S,t)=e^{-r(T-t)}F(S,t)$
6. compute the average `V_Monte_Carlo` of the option prices
7. repeat steps 2-6 until all values are computed

However, as you can see from the image below, the curve of the option prices obtained with the MC simulation is smooth, while what I was expecting was a curve similar to the one of the exact solution. So I made some mistakes somewhere

[image]

```
% S = oil spot prices
S = [ 22.93 15.45 12.61 12.84 15.38 13.43 11.58 15.10 14.87 14.90 15.22 16.11 18.65 17.75 18.30 18.68 19.44 20.07 21.34 20.31 19.53 19.86 18.85 17.27 17.13 16.80 16.20 17.86 17.42 16.53 15.50 15.52 14.54 13.77 14.14 16.38 18.02 17.94 19.48 21.07 20.12 20.05 19.78 18.58 19.59 20.10 19.86 21.10 22.86 22.11 20.39 18.43 18.20 16.70 18.45 27.31 33.51 36.04 32.33 27.28 25.23 20.48 19.90 20.83 21.23 20.19 21.40 21.69 21.89 23.23 22.46 19.50 18.79 19.01 18.92 20.23 20.98 22.38 21.78 21.34 21.88 21.69 20.34 19.41 19.03 20.09 20.32 20.25 19.95 19.09 17.89 18.01 17.50 18.15 16.61 14.51 15.03 14.78 14.68 16.42 17.89 19.06 19.65 18.38 17.45 17.72 18.07 17.16 18.04 18.57 18.54 19.90 19.74 18.45 17.33 18.02 18.23 17.43 17.99 19.03 18.85 19.09 21.33 23.50 21.17 20.42 21.30 21.90 23.97 24.88 23.71 25.23 25.13 22.18 20.97 19.70 20.82 19.26 19.66 19.95 19.80 21.33 20.19 18.33 16.72 16.06 15.12 15.35 14.91 13.72 14.17 13.47 15.03 14.46 13.00 11.35 12.51 12.01 14.68 17.31 17.72 17.92 20.10 21.28 23.80 22.69 25.00 26.10 27.26 29.37 29.84 25.72 28.79 31.82 29.70 31.26 33.88 33.11 34.42 28.44 29.59 29.61 27.24 27.49 28.63 27.60 26.42 27.37 26.20 22.17 19.64 19.39 19.71 20.72 24.53 26.18 27.04 25.52 26.97 28.39 ];
r = .1;    % yearly instantaneous interest rate
T = 1/2;   % expiry time

alpha = 0.0692;
sigma = 0.0876; % values estimated from data
mu = 3.0582;

t = linspace(0,T,numel(S));
tau = T-t;
lambdahat = (mu-r)/alpha;
muhat = mu-sigma^2/2/alpha-lambdahat;

%% Is this V the exact solution?
% this F is the formula (1) on stackexchange
F = exp( exp(-alpha*tau).*log(S) + muhat*(1-exp(-alpha*tau)) + sigma^2/4/alpha*(1-exp(-2*alpha*tau)) );
% K = F(end); % shouldn't we use also the strike price?
V_exact = exp( -r*tau ) .* F; % V contains the prices of the option
plot(t,S)
hold on
plot(t,V_exact)

%% Monte Carlo simulation
n = numel(S);
N = 10000; % number of samples
mustar = mu-sigma^2/2/alpha;
X = zeros(N,n);
X(:,1) = log(S(1));
S = zeros(N,n);
S(:,1) = S(1);
F = zeros(N,n);
V = zeros(N,n);
V_Monte_Carlo = zeros(1,n);
dt = 1; % which values for dt has to be pick?
for k = 2:n
    tau = T-t(k);
    % this X is the formula (2) on stackexchange
    X(:,k) = X(k-1)*exp(-alpha*dt) + mustar*(1-exp(-alpha*dt)) + sigma*sqrt(1-exp(-2*alpha*dt))/sqrt(2*alpha)*randn(N,1);
    S(:,k) = exp(X(:,k));
    F(:,k) = exp( exp(-alpha*tau).*log(S(:,k)) + muhat*(1-exp(-alpha*tau)) + sigma^2/4/alpha*(1-exp(-2*alpha*tau)) );
    V(:,k) = exp(-r*tau)*F(:,k);
    V_Monte_Carlo(k) = mean(V(:,k));
end
plot(t,V_Monte_Carlo,'g')
legend('Spot prices (S)','Option prices (V) from exact solution','Option prices from Monte-Carlo simulation')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see.

You have the following SDE for the stock price under the measure $P$:

$$
dS(t) = \alpha \cdot (\mu - \log S(t)) \cdot S(t) \cdot dt + \sigma \cdot S \cdot dW^P(t),
$$

with initial condition $S(0) = S_0$. Moreover, defining $X(t) = \log S(t)$, assuming a constant market price of risk $\lambda = \mu - r$ and performing a change of measure, you get the process $X(t)$ under the risk neutral measure $Q$ as:

$$
dX(t) = \alpha \cdot \left( \mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha} - \frac{(\mu - r) \cdot \sigma}{\alpha} - X(t) \right) \cdot dt + \sigma\cdot dW^Q(t).
$$

Let's define the drift and diffusion functions:

\begin{aligned}
f(X_t, t) &= \alpha \cdot \left( \mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha} - \frac{(\mu - r) \cdot \sigma}{\alpha} - X_t \right),\\
g(X_t, t) &= \sigma.
\end{aligned}

Now, just apply the EulerMaruyama scheme:

$$
X(t_i) = X(t_{i-1}) + f(X(t_{i-1}), t_{i-1}) \cdot \Delta t_i + g(X(t_{i-1}), t_{i-1}) \cdot \left[ W(t_i) - W(t_{i-1}) \right],
$$

where $W(t_i) - W(t_{i-1}) = \mathcal{N}(0, \Delta t_i)$.

I don't code in Python neither in Matlab, but you can find those implementations in wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method#:%7E:text=In%20It%C3%B4%20calculus%2C%20the%20Euler,equations%20to%20stochastic%20differential%20equations.).

I would recommend using Julia language programming for the simulation of stochastic differential equations.

You want to compute the following derivative price:

\begin{aligned}
V(0) &= E_t^Q \left[D(0, T) \cdot \left( S(T) - K \right) \right]\\
V(0) &= E_t^Q \left[D(0, T) \cdot \left( \exp \left( X(T) \right) - K \right) \right]\\
\end{aligned}

Since the discount factor is deterministic and $K$ is constant:

\begin{aligned}
V(0) &= D(0, T) \cdot \left( E_t^Q \left[  \exp \left( X(T) \right) \right] - K \right)
\end{aligned}

Now, approximate the expectation by a Monte Carlo method. We have to simulate the process $X(t)$ for $N$ paths, evaluate it at time $T$ and apply the exponential function.

$$
E_t^Q \left[  \exp \left( X(T) \right) \right] = \frac{1}{N} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N \exp \left( X_n(T) \right)
$$

The derivative price is

$$
V(0) = D(0, T) \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{N} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^N \exp \left( X_n(T) \right) - K \right]
$$

for any $K$. In particular, if you use $K = F(S_0, T)$ you will get that the derivative price $V(0) = 0$, which is what happens in reality, where $K$ is assumed to take that value. Please, notice that your function $F(S_0, T)$ might have an error, there is a $\sigma$ missing multiplying $\mu - r$, see my code below in function `F` definition. Anyway, removing that $\sigma$ in both the SDE for $X(t)$ and $F(S_0, T)$ yield to correct prices. But I wanted to highlight this difference that I saw in [this](https://www.ucm.es/data/cont/media/www/pag-42885/CommoditiesEE.pdf) paper in Section 2.1.

So, that's it. Here you have the code in Julia:

```
using StochasticDiffEq
using Parameters
using Statistics
using Printf
using Plots

function drift(u, p, t)
  @unpack α, μ, σ, r = p
  return α * ((μ - σ^2 / (2α) - (μ - r) / α) - u)
end

function diffusion(u, p, t)
  @unpack σ = p
  return σ
end

function F(S0, τ, p)
  @unpack α, μ, σ, r = p
  return exp(
    exp(-α * τ) * log(S0) + (μ - σ^2 / (2α) - (μ - r) / α) * (1 - exp(-α * τ)) +
    σ^2 / (4 * α) * (1 - exp(-2 * α * τ))
  )
end

let
  params = (
    α = 0.0692,
    σ = 0.0876,
    μ = 0.25,
    r = 0.10
  )

  S0 = 22.93
  X0 = log(S0)
  T  = 1/2
  trajectories = 100_000

  prob = SDEProblem(drift, diffusion, X0, (0., T), params)
  sde = EnsembleProblem(prob)
  sol = solve(sde, SRIW1(), trajectories = trajectories)

  evs = zeros(trajectories)
  for n in 1:trajectories
    evs[n] = exp(sol[n](T))
  end

  # fair value and standard deviation

  r = params.r
  K = sort(push!(collect(15:0.5:25), F(S0, T, params)))
  x = []
  y = []
  for k in K
    μ = mean(exp(-r * T) .* (evs .- k))
    σ = stdm(evs, μ; corrected = true) / sqrt(trajectories)

    mcapprox = μ
    analytic = exp(-r * T) * (F(S0, T, params) - k)

    push!(x, mcapprox)
    push!(y, analytic)

    # @printf("%e\t%e\n", mcapprox, analytic)
  end
  plot(K, x)
  plot!(K, y)
end
```

I get a derivative price equal to zero when $K = F(S_0, T)$. Also, I get the same price with the Monte Carlo method than with the analytical solution when $K$ is anything else!

Here you can check out a plot with the results, where the approximated values match the analytical results, and $V(0)$ equals $0$ when expected:

[image]

Of course prices can be positive or negative, it depends on the value of the strike $K$. If $K < F(S_0, T)$, the option price is positive because, in order to be fair, the holder (the one that is going to receive $S(T)$), must pay $V(0)$ in advance. The opposite occurs if $K > F(S_0, T)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Yes $r$ is constant, however the problem is that for a forward contract the value of the option at $t=0$ is $V_0=0$ because there is no money exchanged when signing a forward contract. So I really don't know how the comparison has to be performed with the analytical solution (maybe at each time step?). Moreover, may I ask why is not good to use the analytical solution for the forward price in the Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: No, the price of the forward contract is zero only if you select the strike price $K$ accordingly, i.e. if $K = F(S_0, T)$. I believe that the formula $F(S, \tau)$ that you provided is the analytical solution of the expectation given by $E \left[ S(T) \right]$. You see what I mean? Finally, you cannot use the analytical solution for the Monte Carlo method because the Monte Carlo method is a method that is used when you cannot solve the expectation analytically.

Comment: I have updated remark 2 in my answer above as well.

Comment: could you please point out where did you get the function $F(S, \tau)$. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I see what you mean about the use of analytical solution. But I'm struggling to understand the price of the option. The forward price $F(S_0,T)$ is decided before signing the contract and it coincides with the delivery price/strike price, that is $K=F(S_0,T)$, and the payoff is $S_T-K$. My professor says that $V_0=0$ since there is no money exchanged when signing the contract, however this should imply that payoff is always 0 which is not true in general. You can read this in the notes of my professor t.ly/XwHj which also contains the derivation of $F(S, \tau)$.

Comment: Here (from the end of page 2) you can read the previous notes http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~bos/NumericalFinance/AA20/Calibration.pdf where professor  derives the solution of the SDE and derives the PDE for the value of the option

Comment: I have thought again about what you said that we cannot use the analytical solution to compute the spot prices. In the book "Monte Carlo methods in financial engineering" by Glasserman, he says that there is no need to use Monte Carlo if a solution to the PDE for the value of the option exists, but to compute the spot prices he uses the solution to the SDE for the price of the underlying (he doesn't use a method to approximate the solution of the SDE). You can read this here https://i.imgur.com/rCHBnAN.png

Comment: Key point is: if a solution to the PDE exists then there is no need to use Monte Carlo, but in all cases we can use the solution to the SDE to compute the spot prices (using the solution to the SDE is more precise and more simple).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can use the solution of the SDE instead of applying a Monte Carlo discretization scheme (such as Euler). What I meant is that you use the analytical solution of the expectation that yields to the derivative price. That is a different thing. I have already solved the problem in code and will update the answer above so you can check it out.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand thank you very much. Yes the formula $F(S,\tau)$ is the solution of $E[S(T)]$, were you able to see its derivation from the pdf that I sent you? Moreover, did you read in the notes the reasoning about the fact that $V_0=0$? I really don't understand what's going on. Professor asked me to implement the Euler Explict Method for solving the PDE for option prices under the Schwartz mean reverting model, using parameters estimated from data, and then to compare with a Monte Carlo simulation. But if $V_0$ is $0$ what am I supposed to compare?

Comment: I have monthly spot prices from market data, but I don't have $T$ and $K$, should I pick for example $T=2$ (2 years) and then use $K=S_0\exp(rT)=22.93\exp(0.1\times2)=28$?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe I provided all the information required in the question! Thank you!

Comment: I hope it helps! I really dedicated a lot of my Saturday in this answer! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate the time you took to write the answer. About the formula for $dX$ I think the correct one is $dX(t) = \alpha  \left( \mu - \dfrac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha} - X(t) \right)  dt + \sigma dW(t)$ as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/DnAl8V4.png. Moreover, shouldn't $K$ be $24.1$ since $22.93\exp(0.1 \times 1/2) = 24.1$? Now I have to go, but I will read the next part when I will come back. Thanks again for huge help!

Comment: But there is a step missing: the change of measure. There he only applied the Ito's Lemma. The change of measure is missing. I repeat, $K$ can be anything you want!  If you set it equal to $K = F(S_0, T)$, the derivative price is 0. If you use anything else, you can check if the analytical formula matches the Monte Carlo approximation!

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Little by little the puzzle is completing, a missing key point I don't understand is why $K$ is not always equal to $F(S_0,T)$? From what I read $F(S_0,T)$ is the forward price, that is the agreed upon price of an asset in a forward contract. For example I sign with you a forward contract to buy an asset from you at 15€ in 1 year, say that this asset is 10€ now, so $F(S_0,T)=F(10,1)=15$, ie I will have to pay you 15€ at expiry. Now, strike price $K$ is the amount I have to pay at expiry, which is 15€. If the asset price will be 20€ in 1 year then payoff=20-15=5

Comment: I think it is linked with the fact that $F(S_0,T)=E[S_T]$ where the mean is taken w.r.t. the risk neutral measure. Here professor talks about this https://i.imgur.com/7x0G96m.png saying that $K=F(S_0,T)$

Comment: Also, I'm looking in the paper you linked for the definition of the market price of risk $\lambda$ but they never write that it is equal to $\mu-r$, where did you find it?

Comment: Let's address all your questions. In a *Forward* contract $K$ is always equal to $F(S_0, T) = S_0$, so the contract value $V(0) = E[ D(0, T) \cdot (S(T) - S(0)) ]$ is zero. Imagine another contract, let's call it *ModifiedForward*, where $K$ can be any constant. In that case, you can compute its price $V(0)$. We know that $V(0) = D(0, T) \cdot ( E^Q[S(T)] - K)$, so you can use the analytical result of the expectation or compute it using a Monte Carlo approximation and compare those results.

Comment: The value of $\lambda$ in the paper is a constant. I selected to be a constant equal to the number $\mu - r$, but it can be another thing. The analytical results assume it is a constant, so even if I selected it as $\mu - r$, the analytical solutions are still valid. I believe that this value has to be computed some way (fitting data or something, maybe your professor can help us). Sometimes, this value is assume to take a form such that the PDE for the option price can be solved analytically. I just selected a constant, so you can select any other constant and the code will still be correct.

Comment: At this point I believe I have addressed all the required questions in your original question and many more! Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, above I wanted to write $F(S_0, T) = F_0$, not $S_0$, but I cannot modify the comment!

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, you are very kind indeed! I wrote the code in matlab using your formulas and parameters, and the value of the option $V_0$ computed is -2.7238 (do you have this value too?), since it is negative and prices cannot be negative, how do we interpret this value? Does this mean that the option is not profitable and that we will lose money?

Comment: I have updated the answer above in order to address your questions!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just for information, in the original paper by Schwartz (https://sci-hub.st/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb02721.x) the formula for $dX$ does not contain the term $\dfrac{\lambda\sigma}{\alpha}$ but just $\lambda$, so it seems that the multiplication with $\sigma$ and the division by $\alpha$ is made by the researchers who wrote the paper you linked in the answer, maybe is an assumption they made

Comment: This is tricky I guess, paper by Schwartz reports $\alpha\Big(\mu-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}-\lambda\Big)dt$, while other paper reports $\alpha\Big(\mu-\dfrac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}-\dfrac{\lambda\sigma}{\alpha}\Big)dt$, but they both refer to $λ$ as the market price of risk. Maybe $α$ is included inside the $λ$ reported in the paper by Schwartz

Comment: I think that all of them are equivalent because the only important thing is that $\lambda$ is a constant. Then $\alpha \cdot \lambda$ or $\lambda \cdot \sigma$, etc, are just constants. When you fit the model, all these values can lead to the same number, so we have $\alpha \cdot \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 \cdot \sigma$. It would be different if $\lambda$ was assumed to be a function of $X$ in one of the papers, but they all assumed that it is constant. Finally, if $\lambda$ is constant, you can use the analytical solution (eq. 7) in Schwartz paper.

Comment: Thank you rvignolo for long support you have been very kind! Matlab is very powerful too, it takes only 0.26 seconds for analytic solution and MC (1e6 paths) for 22 values of K

Comment: In that time you are including the Monte Carlo simulation, right? Using an Euler-Maruyama scheme? What is the value of `dt` and the maturity `T`?  Just to be on the same page. I would like to benchmark that against C. Is a parallelized run? Could you share the code? Also, is this time including the Monte Carlo simulation or just the mean and variance computations?

Comment: Hi! I stress my question: does that time includes the Monte Carlo simulation, i.e. 1 million paths or just the mean and the analytic value computations? In that case, can you provide insight about the Monte Carlo characteristics?

Comment: Oh I was wrong that time was with 1e5 simulations, with 1e6 it takes 0.8 seconds to compute exact solution option price + MC (spot prices at time T and option prices) for 22 values of the strike K. Consider that I'm using a 10 year old notebook

Comment: Please, I need you to answer the following as precise as posible: Are you taking into account the Monte Carlo simulation in that time? As I understand, you are only considering the time that it takes to price the option once you have the Monte Carlo simulation, but you are not including the Monte Carlo simulation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113526/discussion-between-rvignolo-and-sound-wave).